# uncaugth typerror with coffeescripts generated js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am starting to learn javascript/coffeescript with backbone and I got an error that I don't understand. Any help would be appreciated.

I made a very simple example, with the following `buggy.coffee` coffeescript file:

```
class Panel extends Backbone.Model
p = Panel()  # I instantiate it to trigger the error
```

Which I compiled into `buggy.js` using `coffee -c buggy.coffee`. But when I run it and look at the javascript console, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The error happens in backbone.js (line 256)::

```
var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
  var attrs = attributes || {};
  options || (options = {});
  this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
  this.attributes = {};
  if (options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
  if (options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs, options) || {};
  attrs = _.defaults({}, attrs, _.result(this, 'defaults'));
  this.set(attrs, options);    ### <================================== here
  this.changed = {};
  this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

because `this.set` is undefined.

Now I found a way to avoid the error by editing `buggy.js` (the comment is the original coffeescript generated line):

```
    function Panel() {
      #return Panel.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
      return new Panel.__super__.constructor(this, arguments);
    }
```

But that can't be a real solution.
So what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: p = new Panel(), you miss the keyword 'new'

Comment: thanks. I guess I was tired (asked at 1am), and now I fill quite ashamed :-/ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When instantiating objects in JavaScript, you must use the `new` keyword. `p = Panel()` fails, but `p = new Panel()` will work.

If you don't include the `new` keyword, then `this` is not bound to a new object. Instead, it gets bound to the global object instead. So instead of creating a new `Panel`, you'd be clobbering properties on the global object. You'll also be making calls on that global object (eg. if you write `this.func()`) instead of on your Panel, which is probably the reason this error manifests as "undefined is not a function".

Comment: I appreciate really the explanation on the effect of `new`. As commented in the question, I must have been really tired to forget the new and not realize it alone. But I was also led away by the error and the fact that (1) the constructor can be called without new, and (2) that `this` was actually set to something.